# count files in a list of directories

Tags: linux, bash, find, pipe

I have file with a list of directories that I would like to know how many files are in each directory.

> .../images/idsuffix/userids/

This will give me the count of files and directories for first 5 directories instead of for each directory.

> find ./images/00{0..5}/ | wc

What I want is count of contents for each directory. 
I tried to pass it through xargs but does the same thing and produces a count for all the directories.

```
ls ./images/ > directories.lst  
cat directories.lst | xargs -i{} find {} | wc
```

And this does not produce any output at all.

```
cat directories.lst | xargs -I{} bash -s "find {} | wc"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using sh in the -exec portion of the command you can start an other shell and run your commands in there quite nicely.

> find . -name "*.dat" -exec csh -c 'echo -n $1; grep ID $1 | wc -l' {} {} \;

Or in my case, when counting files in directories. I use "ls -f" as it produces the ls output unsorted which is significantly faster the trying to sort the out put before counting.

with new line beween dir name and count

> find /somedir/some/dir -type d -print -exec sh -c ' ls -f $1/* | wc -l' {} {} \;

Output looks like this

> /dir/somedir/002/1066002
>   6

with tab between dir name and count

> find /somedir/some/dir -type d -exec bash -c 'echo -en "$1\t"; ls -f $1/* | wc -l' {} {} \;

Output looks like this

> /dir/somedir/002/1066002   6

http://www.compuspec.net/reference/os/solaris/find/find_and_execute_with_pipe.shtml

Comment: I don't think you need to pass the find result `{}` twice, since you're only accessing `$1`.

Comment: @DanielBeck with out the second {} the output dose not include the directory name and only shows the count for that directory

Answer (score 5):

You can use a for-loop:

```
for dir in ./images/* ; do echo $dir ; ls "$dir" | wc ; done
```

If you want the dot-files to be included, too, use `ls -a`.

If you want to count files in dot-dirs, too, use `for dir in ./images/* ./images/.*`.

If there are some non-directories, you can add a test:

```
for dir in ./images/* ; do
    if [[ -d $dir ]] ; then
        echo $dir
        ls "$dir" | wc
    fi
done
```

Comment: The test is not necessary if you simply add a trailing slash; e.g. `./images/*/`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read the directory list from a file do:

```
   $ for dir in $(cat directories.lst); do echo "$dir : `ls $dir | wc -l`"; done
```

You do not, however, need the file:

```
   $ for dir in $(find images/ -type d); do echo "$dir : `ls $dir | wc -l`"; done
```

And if you only want top level directories:

```
   $ for dir in $(find images/ -maxdepth 1 -type d); do echo "$dir : `ls $dir | wc -l`"; done
```

Finally, if you have spaces in your file names do:

```
   $ SAVEIFS=$IFS; IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b"); for dir in $(find images/ -type d); do echo "$dir : `ls $dir | wc -l`"; done; IFS=SAVEIFS
```

Comment: [`for x in $(find)` is bad.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)

Comment: Very nice link @grawity, thanks. That is why I use the IFS in my last example though. Still, one more reason why choroba's answer is better :).